# How to get Workflow Variable value from custom activity?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I defined Variables on my Workflow and i want to check the value in my custom activity and change this variable value in some cases.

How can i do it?

Comment: It seems that, whatever you want to do, you're approaching the problem the wrong way. Accessing a variable inside your custom activity without even knowing if it was declared outside it isn't right at all. Can you explain exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Let say i have a variable declared on the workflow and i want to make a check inside my custom activity on this variable. How can i do something like that?

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this is to create an InArgument on your activity and bind the argument to the variable when you drop the activity on the workflow